# drawing electrical fields using pstricks

Tags: pstricks, pst-electricfield

I would like that all the charges has the same colour, but with this code for me it's impossible to make the modify. Could you help me?

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-electricfield}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-6,-6)(6,6)
\psframe*[linecolor=white!50](-6,-6)(6,6)
\psgrid[subgriddiv=0,gridcolor=gray,griddots=10]
\psElectricfield[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=red]
%\psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=blue](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
%\psEquipotential[Q={[-1 -2 2][1 2 2][-1 2 -2][1 -2 -2]},linecolor=green,linewidth=2\pslinewidth,Vmax=0,Vmin=0](-6.1,-6.1)(6.1,6.1)
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

I would also add a point A in my pic (see the figure).
[image]

Answer (score 2):

that is hardcoded in the .pro file (PostScript). You can modify in the
file `pst-elektricfield.pro` the following lines:

```
/drawChargeCircle { % qi x y r on the stack
  0 360 arc 
  gsave 
%  0 ge {1}{0} ifelse setgray fill 
  pop 0 0 1 setrgbcolor fill
  0 setgray stroke
} def
```

then the charges are plotted always in blue (R G B). You can change the
value to whatever you need.

The dot on a field line can be printed with `\psdot[dotscale=3](-5,1.3)`

Comment: How can i modify the radious or every charge? thanks i would like to have circles bigger than now. thanks ;)

Comment: `\psElectricfield[radius=...]`

Comment: I would like also to draw the bounder of the circles. I would like a bounder black. How can i do the correct modify? I tried with this command \draw [color=black,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.3] (-1.0,-2.0) circle (0.6cm); but there is an error. Thank you very much!

Comment: `\draw` is not a command of PSTricks. The boundery is by default black.